# JavaCPP Presets for ONNX : Platform "windows-x86_64" not supported

Tags: java, onnx, javacpp

I'm using this [JavaCPP Presets for ONNX](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/tree/master/onnx) tutorial and I got error with this message in :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Platform "windows-x86_64" not supported by class org.bytedeco.onnx.ISchemaRegistry
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:1162)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:1123)
    at org.bytedeco.onnx.ISchemaRegistry.<clinit>(ISchemaRegistry.java:16)
```

I'm using java and Windows with Cpu ryzen what can I do for fix this?

Comment: Windows is not supported, yet, but contributions are welcome: https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/issues/983

Comment: Thansk @SamuelAudet